# how to loop audio with audio filter in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg and I want to loop the audio until the video ends, but it has to be through the audio filter, the audio has 32 seconds and the video will have 1 minute in this example, I tried the code below but without success:

```
ffmpeg -i image.png -i audio.mp3 -filter:a loop=-1 -r 30 -b:v 1024k -vcodec libx264 -filter:v scale=w=1280:h=720 -t 50 -f mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p outVideo.mp4
```

Can you tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Why only through a filter?

Comment: I is using FFMPEG in javascript with fluent-ffmpeg and has tried to audio loop in various ways and failed, no fluent-ffmpeg has the audioFilter () function, which is where I will use this loop. What kind of something, Example: audioFilter (loop = -1). But I can't do this loop in the filter.

Comment: What would your solution be?

Comment: Add `-stream_loop -1` before the audio `-i`.